# On the partitions of a number

Tags: generating-functions, integer-partitions

I need to find the generating function for number of partitions of $n$ into parts that are divisible by $2$ and every one of them appears at most twice.
I think that solution is $f(x)=(1+x+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x^4+x^8)\cdots$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is the right idea, but your first factor corresponds to part size $1$, which is not divisible by $2$ and hence should appear.  The correct generating function is
$$\prod_{k \ge 1} (1+x^{2k}+x^{4k})$$

Comment: Okey. If I had partition into parts that are powers of number 2, then my solution would be correct right?

Comment: Yes, powers of $2$, each at most twice: $$\prod_{k \ge 0} (1+x^{2^k}+x^{2\cdot2^k})=\prod_{k \ge 0} (1+x^{2^k}+x^{2^{k+1}})$$